# How to hide QMainWindow and show splashcreen during startup?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, splash-screen

I am trying to hide the MainWindow of my Qt desktop app during startup, and to show a splashscreen. Both only happens after the loading phase, even though I call both `splash.show()` and `window.hide()` *before* the loading phase. I tried to split loading phase and constructor, but result is the same. How can I achieve both before the loading phase ?

**Update 1**

To display the splash screen, I had to add a call to QApplication::processEvents()

**Update 2**

The black window was actually not the MainWindow, but a ghost window that popped because `scrollArea->setVisible(true)` was called in the constructor.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPixmap pixmap(QStringLiteral(":/ressources/icons/icon.png"));
    QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);
    splash.show();

    MainWindow window; // this loads for 5-6 seconds
    a.processEvents();
    window.showLoginPrompt();
    splash.finish(&window);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You  are missing the `app.processEvents();` from the example: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html#details](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html#details) In the code you show the message processing / event loop which does all display updates does not happen until a.exec() runs.

Comment: @drescherjm it works for the splash, thanks. It still displays a black mainwindow during loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code and some example I could make it run like you are trying to do.
You only need to call your promptLogin function instead.

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QTimer>
    #include <QSplashScreen>
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
    
        QSplashScreen *splash = new QSplashScreen;
        splash->setPixmap(QPixmap("D:\\Projects\\SplashScreen\\TestSplashScreen\\splash.png"));
        splash->show();
    
        MainWindow mainWin;
    
        QTimer::singleShot(2500, splash, SLOT(close()));
        QTimer::singleShot(2500, &mainWin, SLOT(show()));
    
        return app.exec();
    }
```